# Battery not charging - Dell Latitude 7480, Lubuntu 20.04 in Italy

Tags: lubuntu, dell, power-management, laptop, battery

`upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0` while connected shows

```
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               SMP
  model:                DELL DM3WC64
  serial:               1
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              pią, 19 sie 2022, 06:51:53 (23 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes                                                                                                                                                                  
  has statistics:       yes                                                                                                                                                                  
  battery                                                                                                                                                                                    
    present:             yes                                                                                                                                                                 
    rechargeable:        yes                                                                                                                                                                 
    state:               charging                                                                                                                                                            
    warning-level:       none                                                                                                                                                                
    energy:              0,5624 Wh                                                                                                                                                           
    energy-empty:        0 Wh                                                                                                                                                                
    energy-full:         48,7692 Wh                                                                                                                                                          
    energy-full-design:  54,72 Wh                                                                                                                                                            
    energy-rate:         0 W                                                                                                                                                                 
    voltage:             7,361 V                                                                                                                                                             
    percentage:          1%
    capacity:            89,125%
    technology:          lithium-polymer
    icon-name:          'battery-caution-charging-symbolic'
```

I tried switching "adaptive" to "standard" charging in BIOS.

I tried restarting, `dist-upgrade` and other standard steps.

Problem appeared after travelling to Italy - is it possible that somehow Italian power grid is causing issues? Or maybe it was mechanical damage due to travel?

Battery still worked until it lost entire charge. Laptop works fine when connected to power outlet.

When connected with USB-C charger it charges.

What can be done/checked?

Comment: Do you suspect that even though the battery level displays as 1%, that in reality it is much higher?  You say it "works when unconnected" and even "while travelling."  Based on what I read, it sounds like your battery and charger are performing as normal, but your analytics are skewed.  Does that sound correct?

Comment: Do you have or can you download some other energy consumption/battery analyzer other than Upower?

Comment: @hoatzin It worked while travelling, but battery level was going down as usual. Now I am working solely with power connection.

Comment: @hoatzin I have internet connection so I would able to able download something else but I have no good idea what I should download.

Comment: @hoatzin Tested, battery has no hidden capacity. I now used final 1%.

Comment: @hoatzin On the second, thought - maybe it goes down on reaching 0% because software panicks? System shutdown is triggered: not catastrophic power loss.

Comment: @reducing activity, I think you have a broken cell inside your battery pack (a shorted one) that's why you cannot load it anymore. So buy a new battery-pack on AliExpress or so, and or replace the defective cell inside the pack (mind you if you don't know what you are doing that thing can explode !

Comment: @JorisDonders Do you know how can I confirm is it applicable? Or is it software issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that some sockets in Italy may provide lower amperage.

They should have mismatching socket, but worn out one can fit standard europlug.

It seems that it is what happened, as after return from Italy charging has no issues.